# Recursion & memoization in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, recursion, memoization, dart-null-safety

I'm following a video tutorial on YouTube ( Dynamic Programming - Learn to Solve Algorithmic Problems & Coding Challenges ) from a popular YouTube channel, that teaches in Js, I'm trying to translate it into Dart but some problem occurs, especially I'm struggling with null safety.

Here is the code in Js from the tutorial:

```
const canSum = (targetSum, numbers, memo={}) => {
  if (targetSum in memo) return memo[targetSum];
  if (targetSum === 0) return true;
  if (targetSum < 0) return false;

  for (let num of numbers) {
    const remainder = targetSum - num;
    if (canSum(remainder, numbers, memo) === true) {
      memo[targetSum] = true;
      return true;
      }
    }
  memo[targetSum] = false;
  return false;
};
```

here is my translation in Dart, I believe I have translate correctly,  but it doesn't work ((

```
canSum(targetSum, List<int> array, [Map<int, bool>? memo]) {
  if (memo?.containsKey(targetSum) == true) return memo![targetSum];
  if (targetSum == 0) return true;
  if (targetSum < 0) return false;
  for (int element in array) {
    final difference = targetSum - element;
    if (canSum(difference, array, memo)) {
      (memo ??= {})[targetSum] = true;
      return true;
    }
  }
  (memo ??= {})[targetSum] = false;
  return false;
}
```

Any suggestion? did I mess up with null safety?

Comment: You should be able to fix your code by initializing `memo` *at the beginning*.  Otherwise your initial recursive calls will end up passing `null` for the `memo` cache, and child calls eventually will end up creating their own, separate `Map`s.  Just do: `memo ??= {};` as the first line and remove the other `memo ??= {}` uses.

Comment: It works!I've should be able to understand by myself soon or late ))
Thank you so much!